# Replace a substring with a project property value in SoapUI groovy script

Tags: groovy, replace, substring, soapui

I need to to replace in a query a parameter with a project property value.
Take this example:

`select name from subscribers where phonenb = NEW-CREATE.SUBS.phone and homeaddress = NEW-CREATE.SUBS.address`

I should replace everything that starts with the prefix `NEW-CREATE.SUBS.`
with a project property value whose name comes after this prefix. In my example the project property name would be `phone`

value `0712345678` could be obtained like this: `testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("phone")`

and address

value `England` coming from `testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("address")`

So after this replace my new query should look like:

`select name from subscribers where phonenb = "0712345678" and homeaddress = "England"`

And this query I would be able to run on the DBConn, first parameter from the file and then store the result.

Can anyone provide me such a groovy code?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, please use code tags.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. Do you want the values like `NEW - CREATE.SUBS.phone` to be replaced with their values when run?

Comment: First of all I need to identify in the query all appearances of the prefix "NEW - CREATE.SUBS.", then extract from that string only the variable name: from "NEW - CREATE.SUBS.phone" I need only "phone" for example. And then to replace this variable with its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to identify the property name from the query and then do a replace. The code would look something like this...

```
def query = "select name from subscribers where phonenb = NEW-CREATE.SUBS.phone and homeaddress = NEW-CREATE.SUBS.address"

def regExp = /NEW-CREATE.SUBS.([a-zA-Z]+)/

matcher = ( query =~ regExp )

matcher.each { match ->
    def prop = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue(match[1])
    //update the query
    query = query.replace("NEW-CREATE.SUBS." + match[1],prop)
}

log.info query

//returns
//Tue Apr 08 11:59:58 ADT 2014:INFO:select name from subscribers where phonenb = 999-999-9999 and homeaddress = nowhere to go
```

**Alternate Solution**, Using a prefix stored at project level. The project level property for holding the prefix is called `prefix`

```
def query = "select name from subscribers where phonenb = NEW-CREATE.SUBS.phone and homeaddress = NEW-CREATE.SUBS.address"

def prefix = context.expand('${#Project#prefix}') //get prefix from project level properties.

def regExp = /${prefix}([a-zA-Z]+)/

matcher = ( query =~ regExp )

matcher.each { match ->
    def prop = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue(match[1])
    //update the query
    query = query.replace(prefix + match[1],prop)
}

log.info query

//returns
//Tue Apr 08 15:20:51 ADT 2014:INFO:select name from subscribers where phonenb = 999-999-9999 and homeaddress = nowhere to go
```

Comment: Only one thing is missing from this code: regExp should be set based on a project property value. I have a project property called prefix = NEW-CREATE.SUBS. So is it possible to set the regExp based on this project property value? Something like `def regExp = /${prefix}([a-zA-Z]+)/`

Comment: Only one way to find out :) try it. I think it'll work out. Can you except my answer if it solves your problem?

Comment: I've tried it and didn't work. That's why I asked you :) . I've tried it also like this:`def regExp = /prefix([a-zA-Z]+)/` , without success.

Comment: updated my answer to use prefix from project level properties.